# Storing one-off variables in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing an application that uses an SQLite database to save state between different runs of the program. Most of this state follows a repetitive structure and fits nicely into SQL's relational model. However, there are a few pieces of state that represent global values having to do with user configuration, one-offs that don't make a lot of sense to put into a table.

Is there a standard way to handle such information through SQLite, or RDMSes in general?

Comment: Usually just a table of key-value-pairs makes sense for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a simple table of key-value-pairs like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (key TEXT, value TEXT)
```

And then you can insert records that link variables with names like:

```
INSERT INTO settings (key, value) VALUES ('bg_color', 'red')
```

Then you can leave it to your app to query this table and apply the settings in a context-specific manner.

Comment: In SQLite, `value` does not even need to be TEXT.